# nodejs damage file after delete folder

Tags: node.js, fs

I have tried to delete folder by "rimraf" and "fs-extra" that return callback success but I found a file still there and has been damaged,

in this photo a folder has files 
[image]

(all these files have been deleted except one and isn't as before delete it's damage")[image]

(all these files have been deleted except one and isn't as before delete it's damage")[image]

((all these files have been deleted except one and isn't as before delete it's damage"))

this is a source code of delete folder

```
//remove resource folder
rimraf(path.join(uploadPath,packageName,resourceDirectoryName), (err)=>{                 
   return next();
})
```

Comment: Not having permission to read a file is not the same as having a damaged file. However, you haven't asked a question. But without code we probably cannot help you anyway. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling yes the permission not like damage but i test this file after remove process it's opening and i can read it but after remove process still exist and give me that message

Comment: Have you looked at the error value that is passed to the callback? If the file is not removed then maybe because it cannot be removed. The error might tell you why.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm doing 3 process on this file the first i copy these files and this file passed in this process, it has copied success 
then i remove these files all files have been removed except this file it still exist, then the last process i read new files these i coped in first step when i read files this file give me that message "**error** Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'd:\Nodejs Workarea\node\public\uploads\games\5af1a4b276a12b6b2e4e619b\5af1a4b276a12b6b2e4e619b_HumptyRush\Humpty Rush\description.txt'"

Comment: *"first i copy these files"* Seems like permissions are not set correctly on `description.txt`. Set the correct permissions and it should work. No idea how that works on Windows though.

Comment: set permission on fs.copy function ! or what ? please bring your attention i delete old file not copied file !

Comment: That wasn't clear from your description. Either way, look at and fix the permissions of `description.txt`. The error is telling that this is the problem, so investigate in that direction.